# Determining if an Exp 'e' isClosed based on free variables?

Tags: haskell

I'm not sure where to start or how to write the `isClosed` function below. All help is greatly appreciated! Below is what I have so far.

`isClosed` is supposed to take in a value `e` of type `Exp` and determine if it's closed or not by evaluating as below:

```
-- Identifiers for % expressions and variables
type Id = String

-- The "builtin" functions.
data Op = Succ | Pred | IfZero
           deriving (Show, Ord, Eq)

-- Expressions of L
data Exp = Var Id
         | Nat Integer
         | Op Op
         | Lam Id Exp
         | App Exp Exp
           deriving (Ord, Eq, Show)

-- isClosed e is true if and only if there are no free variables in e
-- "Free" means that the variable it is not declared by a surrounding %.       
-- For example, in the expression

-- x (%x. x (%y.xz)) (%y.x)

-- there are 5 occurrences of x.  The first is "free".  The second is
-- the parameter for the % expression and is never substituted for.
-- The third and fourth occurrences refer to the parameter of the
-- enclosing % expression.  The fifth is free.

-- Examples: (%x. %y. x y) is closed; (%x. y %y. x y) is not since the
-- first occurrence of y is free.

isClosed :: Exp -> Bool
isClosed Lam{} = True
isClosed _ = False
```

Comment: Write an auxiliary function `freeVars :: Exp -> [Id]` to collect al the free variables of an `Exp`. Then, writing `isClosed` becomes trivial.

Comment: @chi I was thinking about doing so but I'm not exactly sure how. I know that'd be easy as we could just use freeVars in isClosed to determine if there are any free variables or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about something like:

```hs
isClosed :: Exp -> Bool
isClosed exp = go [] exp where
  go bindings (Var id)     = id `elem` bindings
  go _        (Nat _)      = True
  go _        (Op _)       = True
  go bindings (Lam id exp) = go (id:bindings) exp
  go bindings (App fn arg) = go bindings fn && go bindings arg
```

let's give it a test ride:

```hs
*Main> isClosed (Var "e")
False
*Main> isClosed (Lam "e" (Var "e"))
True
*Main> isClosed (Lam "e" (Var "x"))
False
*Main> isClosed (App (Lam "e" (Var "x")) (Nat 3))
False
*Main> isClosed (App (Lam "e" (Var "e")) (Nat 3))
True
```

---

**Alternatively**, you can also first write a `freeVars` helper and implement `isClosed` via that:

```hs
isClosed :: Exp -> Bool
isClosed = null . freeVars

freeVars :: Exp -> [Id]
freeVars exp = go [] exp where
  go bindings (Var id)
    | id `elem` bindings   = []
    | otherwise            = [id]
  go _        (Nat _)      = []
  go _        (Op _)       = []
  go bindings (Lam id exp) = go (id:bindings) exp
  go bindings (App fn arg) = go bindings fn ++ go bindings arg
```

and then

```hs
*Main> freeVars (Var "e")
["e"]
*Main> freeVars (Lam "e" (Var "x"))
["x"]
*Main> freeVars (Lam "e" (Var "e"))
[]
*Main> freeVars (App (Lam "e" (Var "x")) (Nat 3))
["x"]
*Main> freeVars (App (Lam "e" (Var "e")) (Nat 3))
[]
```

Comment: The alternative version can also avoid the auxiliary `go` if we exploit `delete` in the `Lam` case, following the mathematical definition of free variable.

Comment: Why does the `acc` arg to `go` need to exist at all? I wrote `freeVars` myself in much the same way, and never found any use for it: it just seems simpler to use `[]` as the base case: https://gist.github.com/amalloy/e385053eea25e3743c90.

Comment: @chi I think you have to do a little more than use `delete`, right? Consider `Lam "f" $ App (Var "f") (Var "f")`: in the lambda body `f` may appear free any number of times, so you either need to `nub` it or else `filter` out all instances of `f`. That is, I assume you were proposing something like https://gist.github.com/amalloy/d22145a4d2bd6bfea96f, which doesn't work unless you make one of the commented substitutions.

Comment: @amalloy You are correct. `delete` only removes the first, so `filter` is the right thing here.

Comment: @amalloy: oh man, you're right... I must have been tired or something. fixed.